# issues while loading new data and using jquery history pushstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some issues while loading my new data after ajax. I have a jquery history pushstate. Here is the code:

```
 $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
 anchorClick(location.pathname);        
 });

 function anchorClick(link) {
 var linkSplit = link.split("/").pop();
 $.get(linkSplit, function(data) {
 var contentarea = $("#content", $(data));
 $("#content").html(contentarea.html());
 });
 }
```

so basically the function is called with the location path to refresh it. I have my ajax. Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
 success : function(data){
 $("#fpcont").html(data);   
 },
```

Basically my success happens using ajax and I data gets processed using php. The data success is suppose to be loaded by id but that never happends. Since the `anchorClick` is disrupting the data location path and what happends is that the page refreshes with the location of the index page. My question is how can I stop my anchorClick and load my ajax properly?

Comment: I have tried setting the `linkSplit = false`

Comment: I have also tried setting my `anchorClick() = false`

Comment: I also tried setting my `anchorClick(null)` but my ajax will not process after that...

Comment: Where and when is that 2nd AJAX request executed?